# crear una clase lock para select2 que no se pueda borrar

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Estoy tratando que crear una clase **`.lock`** que no se pueda eliminar. 
La idea es hacer que el elemento `option` que tenga esta clase no sea posible borrarlo.

Logré hacer que la clase se transpasara entre los elementos, pero no logro desactivar el borrado del **select2**

```js
function setClass(data, container){
 if(data.element){
  $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
 }
 return data.text;
}; 

$(".select2").select2({
 templateResult: setClass,
 templateSelection: setClass,
});
```

```css
.select2-container{
  width:100% !important;
}
.select2-selection__choice.lock{
    background:blue;
    }
.select2-selection__choice.lock .select2-selection__choice__remove{
      display:none !important;
    }

.select2-results__option.lock{
    display:none;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

 <select class="select2" multiple>
   <option class="lock" value="lock" selected>lock</option>
     <option value="1" selected>1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

**//ACTUALIZACION**
 hice un filtro por la clase ´lock´ pero de todas arroja un error en el .select2("close");
de todas formas me funciona para lo que necesito.

```js
function setClass(data, container) {
  if (data.element) {
    //si un elemento tiene un atributo, lo agrega al container como una clase  
    $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
  }
  return data.text;
};


$(".select2").select2({
  templateResult: setClass,
  templateSelection: setClass,
  width: '100%',
}).on("select2:unselecting", function(e) {
  // si el elemento era "lock" (que no lo queremos borrar)
  if ($(e.params.args.data.element).hasClass('lock')) {
    // evita la acción por defecto
    e.preventDefault();
    // cierra el menú de select2
    //$(".select2").select2().trigger("select2:close");
    $(".select2").select2("close");
  }
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice.lock {
  background: blue;
}

.select2-selection__choice.lock .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  display: none !important;
}

.select2-results__option.lock {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="select2" multiple name="select">
   <option class="lock" value="NOMBRE" selected>NOMBRE</option>
   <option class="lock" value="APELLIDO" selected>APELLIDO</option>
   <option value="EMAIL" selected>EMAIL</option>
   <option value="Elefante">Elefante</option>
   <option value="DIRECCION">DIRECCION</option>
   <option value="rut">RUT</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Hola Ivan, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas, te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: No me queda clara la pregunta: ¿qué es lo que quieres conseguir? Que en una selección múltiple haya un elemento siempre seleccionado y que no se pueda eliminar?

Comment: @PabloLozano si, estoy tratando de hacer una clase que no se pueda borrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una cosa que puedes hacer es añadir un controlador del evento de borrado de etiqueta (`select2:unselecting`) y comprobar el nombre de la etiqueta que se va a borrar. Si coincide con la que no quieres que se borre, entonces evita la acción por defecto.

Algo como esto:

```js
function setClass(data, container) {
  if (data.element) {
    $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
  }
  return data.text;
};

$(".select2").select2({
  templateResult: setClass,
  templateSelection: setClass,
})
// cuando se borre un elemento
.on("select2:unselecting", function(e) {
  // si el elemento era "lock" (que no lo queremos borrar)
  if (e.params.args.data.text == "lock") {
    // evita la acción por defecto
    e.preventDefault();
    // cierra el menú de select2
    $(".select2").select2("close");
  }
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice.lock {
  background: blue;
}

.select2-selection__choice.lock .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  display: none !important;
}

.select2-results__option.lock {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" multiple>
  <option class="lock" value="lock" selected>lock</option>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Originalmente me aparecían dos opciones "lock" (la que no se puede borrar y otra que estaba en proceso de borrado), pero mirando en Internet encontré esta [pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21648246/3695983), donde en las respuestas se sugería usar el `select2("close")` para evitar ese comportamiento.